# How to change HTML background color in Javascript - IE9 issue

Tags: javascript, html, colors, background, internet-explorer-9

I've got problem with dynamically background changing in whole HTML document. Here is piece of code:

```
function changeHTMLBackground() {

  var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
  html.style.background = "#ff00ff";    
}
```

Problem appears only in IE9. In Chrome, FF, Opera works fine. I know there is one solution to change "body" instead of "html", but it isn't solution for me, I need to change style for HTML tag.

Comment: "... problem appears...," what problem exactly? I'm guessing nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the problem is but here are a few possible solutions.
1) Maybe the selector isn't working.
try using

```
document.html.style.backgroundColor = "#977689";
```

2) Maybe IE9 has an issue with html bg colors anyway. is the CSS code working?

3) try adding a class and id to the html tag, and selecting the element with that.

Comment: It was other problem - I'm using gradient in CSS for HTML tag, in short version:

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #85b2d3 0%,#a7c7dc 32%,#a7c7dc 99%); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#85b2d3', endColorstr='#a7c7dc',GradientType=0 );


I set solid color in CSS for HTML tag and then Javascript code works. 
When I have "filter: ..." Javascript fails. 
Selector works fine. CSS code is working.

Any sugestions?

Comment: Well, IE obviously still supports those filter properties. So I'm guessing that even when you update the background color, the filter property overrules it. There's probably some Microsoft specific Javascript code to disable the filter.
But the most simple way would be define class names and toggle them with Javascript. You can include the correct Backgrounds for each class.

Comment: Fabrício Matté - I was actually not sure... I'm sure you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `backgroundColor` property and apply it to the document body:

```
function changeHTMLBackground() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ff00ff";
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/kTUyz/) - works in all browsers including IE9

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('document').ready(function(){
    $("#textfield").focus(function () {
      $('.class').css(' background-color','#ff00ff');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that IE does not support applying CSS to the html tag itself, nor am I sure that's expected by the standard. As a trivial test, try:

```
<!doctype html><html style="background: green"><body>Testing</body></html>
```